# Shouldn't the Deep Space Nine crew now be in TOS episode "Trouble with Tribbles?"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos

I just got done watching the DS9 episode "Trials and Tribble-ations". In the episode some of the crew from DS9 go back in time to the the time of TOS "Trouble with Tribbles." Now Sisko, Dax, Odo, O'brien, Worf, etc. are in some of the scenes with Kirk, Spock, etc.

I decided to watch "Trouble with Tribbles" again afterwards, but the relevant DS9 crew is not in the original episode.

Since they traveled back in time and have become part of the timeline shouldn't they now be in all of those scenes? All kidding aside has anyone tried to remake the "Trouble with Tribbles" episode and add the DS9 crew into the relevant scenes?

Comment: That's a great suggestion, you should do that.

Comment: @cde Lmfao! I think you're probably more up to the challenge then me.

Comment: There's a mention of a fan edit here by TheFixer but no links. You could contact them direct; http://originaltrilogy.com/forum/topic.cfm/Star-Trek-Fan-Edits/topic/6452/

Comment: @Richard I looked everywhere for the video. It looks like others tried to get links but he never responded. The post is so old, circa 2006...but I'm gonna set up an account tonight to see if I can reach him. Thanks for the link.

Comment: While we're at it, NX-01 is missing from the Enterprise recreation deck in The Motion Picture and the conference room trophy walls on the Enterprises-D and E.

Comment: @Politank-Z Do you really consider the NX-01 an "Enterprise?" For that matter do you consider the series "Enterprise" to be part of the Star Trek Universe? LOL

Comment: @JMFB As much, if not more of, an Enterprise than the other examples on the rec deck wall. The final season of Enterprise: as much, if not more of, a part of the Star Trek universe (multiverse) than much of the animated series, The Final Frontier, several episodes of Voyager, much of the first seasons of Enterprise, and the Abramsverse.

Comment: Also, Generations. *shudder*

Comment: @Politank-Z The animated series was there mainly because of a revival of ST in the early 70's and to continue low budget since there weren't funds or the desire by network executives to relaunch the series at that time. As for one or more movies being bad, each one is a two hour gaffaw(Nemesis was hard to get through as well). I love Voyager and can name way more DS9 episodes that are way worse then Voyager episodes. Every series had bad episodes, try rewatching season one of TNG for the most part or anything that centered around Troi.

Comment: @JMFB And what critique of Enterprise do you have which distinguishes your list from mine? I wasn't listing what I find bad per se (that is a longer list which doesn't include everything I mentioned), but what simply doesn't fit. The Larry Niven episodes of TAS, amongst others, don't fit. Final Frontier and Generations don't fit. There are aspects of the Abramsverse which I enjoy, but on the whole, it really doesn't fit.

Comment: @Politank-Z I don't know what you mean by don't "fit." I was referring to an actual series, the only one I can think of, that went directly back into another series and added its characters there. I was just referencing a fairly isolated occurrence, at least that I can remember. But we cannot keep doing a back and forth without heading to chat, it's against the rules...

Comment: I'm afraid the Captain's log only captured the original timeline.

Comment: @MajorStackings I'm not sure what the captains log has to do with background characters being in a shot. For example the scene where the fight breaks out on the station. At the end of the episode when Kirk hands Sisko the report back Sisko should be added as well.

Comment: @JMFB I'm suggesting in jest that the DS9 episode is an alternate timeline than the TOS episode and we didn't get to see any DS9 personnel because they aren't in the TOS timeline. They are in DS9's altered version of the TOS timeline. Timey wimey logic on my part.

Comment: @MajorStackings Yes I considered that answer when I wrote the question. Actually the answer below suggests it, not in jest I might add. I actually want to see that fan footage from the link Richard posted, but have not as of yet found it.

Comment: @JMFB So it's the second question, and you are kidding with the title question? Otherwise we'll see somebody post *Why aren't there more Marty's in BTTF1 since we saw them in BTTF2?* and *Why isn't old Arnie in T1 since we see him in the trailer for the latest T flick?*

Comment: @MajorStackings Ha Ha, lol. I was pointing out a flaw in my question so to speak, and in the body explained that if they're going to do something like this they should release a new updated TOS episode which would be easy enough for them to do since they have all the raw footage. I am surprised that this got 8+ 0- votes, I've asked a lot better questions that got less votes. I'll chalk it up to people liking Tribbles I guess, who doesn't, right? I'd love to find that fan video and watch it. We need to move this to chat though and I don't have time right now.

Comment: @Richard So I did create an account, sent him a private message, and posted a comment under it. The last time he logged on was 2011. I dug around a little, did some computer magic, and found out his first name is Jay last initial B from Georgia. I also found his email address and website, but I don't know if his email current since it's an AOL account. I sent him an email as well. His website is: http://www.angelfire.com/ga/PhineasBog/  Any idea who the guy is?

Comment: I think "Trials and Tribble-ations" was structured in such a way that the time travelers always remained "off-camera" from all TOS shots, so including them would not be a simple matter of insertion into existing TOS scenes, but at least re-framing and therefore re-shooting scenes. I think the whole idea behind the DS9 episode was that they were dancing on the edge of consequential alterations to the timeline and effectively remaining unnoticed (at least those indigenous to the TOS timeline remained oblivious to and unaffected by the visitors from the future).

Answer (score 15):

There are two possibilities as to why the DS9 crew do not appear in the events of TOS episode S02E15 "[The Trouble with Tribbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Tribbles)":

[image: Sisko, seated, looks over his right shoulder as Dax, behind him with a pad and stylus looks in the same direction. A number of tribbles clutter the console in front of them, to the right of the picture]

### Separate Timelines

If we view the original episode as a separate timeline from the altered one we witness in DS9 episode S05E06 "[Trials and Tribble-ations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trials_and_Tribble-ations)", then it becomes obvious that the TOS episode represents the original, unaltered timeline.

This would mean that all events AFTER "Trials and Tribble-ations" take place in an alternate timeline - one in which the DS9 crewmembers were present on that day in 2268.

### Off-Screen Events

If, however, we assume a single timeline, then we must account for how the DS9 crewmembers could be present yet not appear in "The Trouble with Tribbles". The most apparent explanation is that the DS9 crewmembers WERE there as depicted, but never appeared on-screen due to viewing angles and/or camera timing.

### Summary

Given that DS9 crewmembers were digitally inserted into existing scenes from the TOS episode, we are most likely looking at the "alternate timeline" explanation. This is even hinted at in the dialogue between Sisko & the Temporal Investigators.

> **LUCSLY:** Regulation one fifty seven, section three, paragraph eighteen.
> Starfleet officers shall take all necessary precautions to minimise
> any participation in historical events.
>
> **SISKO:** All right. It was a mistake. But there were no lasting repercussions.
>
> **DULMUR:** How do you know that? For all we know, we could be living in an alternate
> timeline right now.
>
> **SISKO:** If my people had caused any changes in the timeline, we would
> have been the first to notice when we got back.

Although Sisko may be correct that his people would have noticed any major changes, it's highly unlikely that a minor event - such as Sisko & Dax now appearing in the background of a security recording - would be noticeable.

### Side-by-Side Comparison

If you would like to see a comparison of scenes from each episode, J. Trent Adams made a site that compares the TOS & DS9 episodes. The page is old, but AFAIK it's the only one of its kind that compares details of each edited scene with the original. The site itself is gone, but [here is a link to it](https://web.archive.org/web/20111007062943/http://www.skotophile.com/StarTrek/Tribbles.html) on the Internet Archive:

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. You gave me a lot to digest. Let me consider it. If you can find the footage of that fan made episode and post it here I'd definitely give you a correct answer. I haven't as of yet found it. Richard posted a link to the guys website in the above comments.

Comment: @JMFB: You might also try [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-krlbfYhBz0), as well as some of its relatives.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. I've seen that one before. I'd love to see the remake that fan did, but nobody from the site, or he ever got back to me... :(

Comment: "Although Sisko may be correct that his people would have noticed any major changes" - really? If you got back from the past and there were a million Mongolians who didn't exist now, would you notice? (Or pick another far away country if you're from Mongolia)

Comment: @colmde - precisely the point of the two temporal investigators, there's just no way to know what changed. Hence the term "may be right".  Then again, if those million Mongolians don't affect history in any major way, doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: Heads up, the skotophile link has died and since been taken over by a domain squatter

Comment: @Pingcode - Thanks for catching that, I updated it with an archive of the page instead

Comment: I always wondered what happened to the two guys that Bashir and O'Brien replaced in the post-brawl line-up in front of Kirk.  Could one have them been promoted earlier because he didn't have that reprimand in his jacket?  Could he have given an assignment that he wasn't ready for?  Think about it.